# Using mustache.js along with node.js?

Tags: node.js, mustache

After becoming fond with mustache.js template-style, I would like continue using it in node.js.

I've been able to install it and confirm that it's working, but I just can't get my head around how to use it to template files.

How do I load a template called `template.html` and apply mustache's magic to it within node.js?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`fs.readFileSync` is the synchronous version of `fs.readFile`, so it will be blocking. Here's a basic example of how you could use `fs.readFile` with mustache.js which would return the mustache template in the callback.

```
var object_to_render = {key: "value", ...};

fs.readFile(path_to_mustache_template, function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var output = Mustache.render(data.toString(), object_to_render);

  // do something with output... 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Didn't notice that it was synchronous, but it did the job. Welcome to SO BTW :)

Comment: Awesome :) The example is just one of the ways I've been including mustache templates; there's probably other/better ways

Answer (score 7):

I ended up making a tiny helper function to load a template file as a string;

```
function loadTemplate(template) {
    return this.fs.readFileSync(app.set('views') + template+ '.html').toString();
}

var html = Mustache.to_html(loadTemplate('myView'), {key: "value", ...});

res.send(html);
```